# Query for repeating sequences in SQLite

Tags: subquery, sqlite, sequence

I have an SQLite DB, let's assume the id can be considered as the order of rows, I want to find repeating sequences in the table according to certain criteria.

consider this example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/dbdb0/1)

schema + data:

```
CREATE TABLE eventLog 
    (
     id integer primary key autoincrement, 
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('power', 'power on');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('cleaner', 'cleaning started');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('cleaner', 'cleaning finished');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('power', 'power off');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('power', 'power on');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('cleaner', 'cleaning started');

INSERT INTO eventLog
(type, details)
VALUES
('power', 'power off');
```

Basic query:

```
select * from eventLog
order by id asc
```

result:
[image]

I've highlighted some sequences:
if I look at repeating sequences in "details" the result should be the ids: [1,2][5,6]
and if I look at the "type" column the result should be [[1,2][5,6]],[[3,4][6,7]].

Is there a way to query for repeating sequences without external programing - using SQL only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OLAP or window functions. Example for details, you can add a derived column for type as well:

```
 select *
 from (  
    select id, type, details
     , lead(id) over (order by id) as lead_id
     , lead(details) over (order by id) as lead_details
    from eventLog
 ) as t
 where t.details = 'power on' and t.lead_details = 'cleaning started'
  ;
```

If you want a more generic solution, you can add a table that contains consecutive pairs that you are interested in, and use that in your query

If you don't care for which details that are consecutive, merely that they occur several times:

```
select id, type, details, lead_id, lead_details
from (  
  select id, type, details, lead_id, lead_details
     , count(1) over (partition by details, lead_details) cnt
  from (  
    select id, type, details
     , lead(id) over (order by id) as lead_id
     , lead(details) over (order by id) as lead_details
    from eventLog
  ) as t
) as tt
where cnt > 1;
```

You can even look for repetitions of various length, here 2 and 3:

```
select id, type, details, lead_id, lead_details
from (  
  select id, type, details, lead_id, lead_details
     , count(1) over (partition by details, lead_details) cnt
     , count(1) over (partition by details, lead_details, lead2_details) cnt2
  from (  
    select id, type, details
     , lead(id) over (order by id) as lead_id
     , lead(details) over (order by id) as lead_details
     , lead(details,2) over (order by id) as lead2_details
    from eventLog
  ) as t
) as tt
where cnt > 1
 or cnt2 > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/owyQkDGU)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, here you've explicitly declared the order, Can the query find any repeating sequence (I have ALOT of things that I want to search for sequences)

Comment: I updated the fiddle in my answer with a "pattern" table (named it consecutive_detail_pairs), is that what you are looking for? You can add as many consecutive details as you like there

Comment: Basically, I prefer to do it without any additional info, can it be a loop that looks for all sequence possibilities (I know, it will be slow as hell) and returns all tuples (there might be a sequence that is longer than 2 items) that appear more than once?

Comment: so, your basic problem is finding consecutive typåe/details repeated more than once?

Comment: yes, repeating sequences of a column according to the order defined by autoincrement id. it can be more than 2 items sequence (i.e. A,B,C,D,A,B,C,A,D,A,B) will return A,B,C x2, A,B x3. Sequence that appear once can be ignored

Comment: For all consecutive numbers between 2 and n-1, where n is the number of rows in the table, you will need another strategy. A strategy that I currently don't know. If I come up with something, I'll post an update

Comment: And if we will limit it for 2 or 3 items, will it be possible?

Comment: @yossico, yes, then it is fairly easy to do

Comment: @yossico, updated my answer

Comment: Nice solution for a fixed pattern set.